# How many operation are required to sort a array of numbers.

Tags: algorithms, sorting

On StackOverflow, a simple question inspired me to create an equation for a answer. But it turn out that, it is kind of complicated (IMHO) mathematical problem, namely:

> Given an array of n elements, is it possible in O(n) time, to figure
>   out how many operations* will be required, if we were to sort that
>   array of elements using bubble sort algorithm ?

**total number of swaps.*

Comment: By operations, I presume you mean number of swaps? Interesting question.

Comment: @Aryabhata, yes. I will update my question with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so. This is equivalent to computing the [Kendall tau coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance). There are a [couple algorithms](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/999) for doing this ([one of which involves using a Merge sort to compute how many steps Bubble sort would take](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient#Algorithms)) but they are $O(n\cdot log\ n)$.

Comment: Now I also believe is not possible. Thank you for your time.